# Unable to import numpy

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip

I'm on OS X Mavericks and new to Python. I have the Apple python environment and installed the official one from python.org.

When I try to import numpy from the python interpreter I get that the module can't be found.

```
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

When I run:

```
$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

When I run the following commands on the terminal I get the following:

```
$which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

$which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

what to do because I'm going crazy!!!

Comment: what's the output of `import sys; print([sys.prefix, getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)])` at the python prompt?

Comment: Did you check within the library to see if you can access the numpy module, I have seen some installs where the permissions did not let a user get to the installed library. Since it was installed, the pip install would tell you so even though the regular user could not get to it. If you can run as root, see if the import works as route (try interactive python with the import)

Comment: @IfLoop >>> import sys; print([sys.prefix, getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)])
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', None]

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use a virtualenv. Using a virtualenv you can have detailed control of the installed packages. See http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: You could try a pip [user install](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs) as a work around, to get it to install to a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with numpy and other libraries common to scientific packages like matplotlib. You might try installing a Python distribution package like Anaconda, which includes several other useful libraries similar to numpy. Install link here: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not deleting the 'numpy' in python2.7 because it is a built-in module of python2.7 by macOS.
Try:`python3 -m pip install numpy`