# Error importing numpy after upgrading with pip

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip

This question is related to a question here: [Unable to import numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079744/unable-to-import-numpy)

I ran: sudo pip install --upgrade numpy

then when I ran python and tried to import numpy I got this strange error!!! I'm going crazy!

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so, 2): Symbol not found: __gfortran_compare_string
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
>>>
```

EDIT:
I also ran this:

```
$ pip show numpy
---
Name: numpy
Version: 1.8.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `pip show numpy`?

Comment: @RobWatts updated the question with an EDIT

Comment: Hmmm... pip shows the right version. Is there a `version.py` in the numpy directory? If so, what version does it say it has in there?

Comment: @RobWatts http://pastebin.com/v5HZ2eRG

Comment: Well, it looks like python isn't trying to get an old version of numpy. I had that happen to me in a slightly different situation, but it is good to confirm that that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me to was to manually install gcc via macports:

```
sudo port install gcc48
```

... which installs gfortran, but without the alias that numpy seems to be expecting (gfortran).  Then we make a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8 /opt/local/bin/gfortran
```

After that, I uninstalled and reinstalled numpy via pip and it works like a charm.

This fixed the issue for me on mavericks last night.  From what I've read, gfortran used to be part of the OS X command line tools, but isn't as of Lion or so.  Installing gcc separately "fixes" that.